# What is the reference that Star Wars Empire at War: Forces of Corruption makes to Talon Karrde?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, video-games

In the video game *Star Wars Empire at War: Forces of Corruption* there is a reference to Talon Karrde from the *Thrawn* Trilogy (according to Wookieepedia). I love the characters Tyber Zahn and Talon Karrde, so I was curious what this reference is.

What is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Talon Karrde is referenced when you corrupt Myrkr

[image]

[image]